# Cant access deployed app on GCP using Docker. How can I make it available?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I just deployed a web app to a GCP instance using a docker container. I'm new at this and it is my first time doing it. The problem is that I can't access the app via the external ip. I only have available ports 80 and 443 in the firewall, but right now I'm just running it on the port 80. I already tried doing a wget localhost:80 and this is what it shows:

```
--2024-01-10 19:43:40--  (try: 3)  http://localhost/
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

The docker container is running without a problem. I don't know if this has with the docker-entrypoint. I didn't specify one, I just create my Next.js app using a simple dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And use this commands to start the container:

```
docker build -t project . && docker run -dp 80:80 project
```

Comment: googles firewall is still blocking

Comment: Try to open all ports on firewall to confirm that is the issue

Comment: Where are you testing `localhost`? If on the same machine as Docker, the VPC firewall is not the issue. If you are testing from a remote computer, you cannot specify `localhost` as the hostname. Use the external (public) IP address and verify that the firewall rule is attached to your VM. Your post requires a lot more details to solve your problem. Tip: check the Docker logs for your container to see if there are errors starting your container.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't open the port of the instance and also in the package.json I forgot to specify the port for the npm start. Thank you all!

Comment: Please add more details on what you changed/improved. You have provided tips but not a good fact based answer.